# TelosB working onContiki

Tags: contiki

while doing hello-world program for telosB using Contiki OS, I faced a problem:

when I type make `hello-world.upload` after connecting telosB mote, I get the following comments in ubuntu.

`../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:481:1: fatal error: opening dependency file obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.d: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
../../Makefile.include:193: recipe for target 'obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o' failed
make: *** [obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o] Error 1
rm hello-world.co`

pl do help why this happend and how to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you (or someone else) has built his application previously as a different user, possibly root. Hence your current user does not have write permissions on those build files.

To delete them, `make clean` as root:

```
sudo make clean TARGET=sky
```